# Are Asana stories guaranteed to be returned in time order sequence?

Tags: asana

While trying the Asana API for task `stories` I noticed that the server sends back a list of all the stories in time-ordered sequence i.e sorted on the `created_at` field. The first element in the list is the first story of that task and the last item is the latest story. Is this ordering guaranteed by design? And can this be relied upon in the code? I want to get the latest activity by looking at the last element of the returned list. [Documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#stories) has no such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, we order stories by creation time in any situation where you get a set of stories. I'm adding that to the documentation now. Thanks for the catch!